# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать задачу с помощью генерации исключений?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать задачу с помощью генерации исключений? Если есть переменная pin. Переменная pin должен принимать только числа и должен состоит только из 4 чисел. Если введется неправильное данные то должен выводится сообщение «вы ввели неправильное значение» или «pin должен состоит из 4 чисел».

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: С помощью блока try except и, например, вылавливанию ошибок IndexError и TypeError. А может тебе надо своё исключение создать с нужными проверками. Покажи что уже получилось сделать и в чем конкретней проблема с реализацией.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял по названию переменной и контексту "из 4 чисел" это на самом деле "из 4 цифр".

С помощью блока try-except. К примеру используя исключение *ValueError*.
Или второй вариант, с помощью ключевого слова **assert**:

```
assert isinstance(pin, int) and len(str(pin)) == 4, "Вы ввели неправильное значение"
```

Как это работает:

**assert** принимает условие, и если оно не является истинным, вызывает исключение *AssertionError*.

По мимо условия, **можно** передать строку, которая будет выведена вместе с исключением, *если условие не подтвердится.*